# Wordpress Displaying filtered list of matching taxonomies on page

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, taxonomy

I have three related taxonomies
tax1 = make and tax2 = body and tax3 = make-body

tax3 is a combination of the first two

I would like to show links from the 'make' archive page to all the 'make-body' archive pages that have posts (not showing links to empty archive pages)

I would then like to do the reverse on the 'body' archive pages.

So I need to partial match 'show me an array of 'make-body' slugs that are not empty AND match the current archive page's 'body' or 'make'

The cream on the cake would be if I could put a count of the available 'make-body' after the link.
I am no expert (understatement) in php but I can see that this returns a list of the 'make-body' slugs and the slug of the current archive page.

Struggling to filter the 'make-body' results to only show results relevant to the page.

I assume I Then have to implode the array and add the rest of the URL to the slug...

Thanks for any help here (this is the first time of posting, so I am sure I have trodden roughshod over all etiquette!)

So far I have the following which builds an array (borrowed from another SO question)

```html
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'body' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    }   
    $filter =($term->slug);
    $termArgs = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'make-body',
    'field'    => 'term_id',
    'terms'    => get_terms( 'make-body', array( 'hide_empty' => true, 'fields' => 'slugs')),
    'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'body',
    'terms'    => $filter,
    'field'    => 'slug'
    )
    )
    );
    print_r($termArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work based on matching the first part of the taxonomy.  This now gives me all terms that start with the parent taxonomy term with a link to the archive page.

```html
$categories = array();
$names = array(); 
$reg = '/^'. ($term->slug) .'/';
    $category_list_items = get_terms( 'your-taxonomy', array( 'hide_empty' => true, ));
    foreach($category_list_items as $category_list_item){
    if(! empty($category_list_item->slug) ){
        $categories[] = $category_list_item->slug;
        $names[] = $category_list_item->name;
    }
}
foreach ($categories as $key=>$category) {
     if(preg_match($reg,$category)){
     echo "<a  href=/absolute-path/".$category ."/>"; 
    echo $names[$key] . " items</a> |";
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'listing', 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'your-taxonomy' => $category, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
}
}
```